# Limit of general solution of ordinary differential equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is
$$t\dot{x}+(1+\alpha t)x=t$$
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x(t)$ the general solution.

For what $\alpha$ does the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)$ exist and what is this limit?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this problem, and where do you get stuck?

Comment: @mickep I don't know how to begin here, what strategy should I follow?

Comment: One way would be to solve the differential equation using integrating factor. Do you know of that method?

Comment: @mickep Yes I do, but how do I solve the limit question when I have the solution (unfortunately I can't solve the equation right now)

Comment: What should I say without the function? You will have an explicit function $x(t)$, and you should try to evaluate $\lim_{t\to+\infty}x(t)$. Have you done limits before? There is a short cut: _If_ the limit exists and $x'(t)\to 0$ as $t\to+\infty$, then the limit $X$ of $x(t)$ must satisfy (look at the equation) $1/\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll help you solving the differential equation, and leave the question of limit to you. Try hard, and then tell if you need further help.

You can write your differential equation
$$
x'(t)+\bigl(\alpha+\frac{1}{t}\bigr)x(t)=1
$$
Thus, an integrating factor is
$$
\exp\Bigl(\int \alpha+\frac{1}{t}\,dt\Bigr)=\exp(\alpha t+\log t)=t\exp(\alpha t).
$$
Multiplying the differential equation with the integrating factor,
$$
\bigl(t\exp(\alpha t) x(t)\bigr)'=t\exp(\alpha t).
$$
Integrating,
$$
t\exp(\alpha t)x(t)=\int t\exp(\alpha t)\,dt=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\bigl(\alpha t-1\bigr)\exp(\alpha t)+C,
$$
where $C$ is some arbitrary constant. Dividing by $t\exp(\alpha t)$, we get
$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{\alpha^2t}+C\frac{\exp(-\alpha t)}{t}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

divide through by $t$ and take $\lim_{t\to \infty}$ and the d.e to solve is

$$ \dot x +\alpha x = 1 $$

with solution

$$ x(t) = A e^{- \alpha t} + \frac 1 \alpha$$

Comment: I think the de to solve is $\dot{x}+(1/t+\alpha)x=1$

Comment: Taking limit as $t\to\infty$ and _then_ solving is not exactly meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

the homogeneous equation $$\dot x + \left(\frac 1t + \alpha\right) x = 0$$ has the solution $$x = \frac A t e^{-\alpha  t}, \text{ $A$ is a constant.} \tag 1$$ at the minimum you will need $\alpha \ge 0$ for the limit of $x$ as $t \to \infty$ to exist.

we can try variation of parameters to try and find a particular solution of $$ \dot x + \left(\frac 1t + \alpha\right) x = 1$$ differentiating $(1)$ logarithmically, we have $$\frac {\dot x} x = \frac{\dot A}{A} - \frac 1t - \alpha \to \dot A = A\to A = ae^t \text{where $a$ is a constant. }$$

we have the solution $$x = \frac a t e^{(1-\alpha)  t} \to 0 \text{ as long as  } \alpha \ge 1. $$